# WearOS - Is there a way to collect raw data from ECG sensor?

Tags: android, wear-os, samsung-mobile

I was hoping WearOS HealthServices provide a way to fetch raw ECG samples, but ECG isn't among MeasureClient's supported DataTypes. Is there another way to obtain these readings?

GalaxyWatch4 contains "BioActive" sensor set that has electrodes for acquiring RA-LA voltage difference, so I'm wondering how to access those readings (same goes for impedance, but that is secondary rn)

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Samsung [Privileged Health SDK](https://developer.samsung.com/health/platform/overview.html#Samsung-Privileged-Health-SDK) provides raw electrocardiogram sensor data.

Comment: On the website above, Samsung made it sound like SDK is quite exclusive and just high profile companies can get their hands on this sort of data - do you have experience getting access to this SDK by any chance? I'd use it for academic purposes so I'm wondering if they would grant access to individuals or academic institutions for non-commercial use.
Thank you for the answer! :)

Comment: @DragicaNikolic The [programming guide](https://developer.samsung.com/health/android/data/guide/intro.html) describes it all in detail; while I'd assume that you'd have to be a corporation, featuring a DUNS number. Unsure who they'd accept as a partner, but when the institution you may be working/learning at would apply for partnership, the chances might be a whole lot better than as a private person. Proven HIPPA compliance might be required for this.

Comment: And you can't just use any backend system, but something alike the [Google Cloud Healthcare Data Engine](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare), which also is HIPPA compliant. This is highly sensitive personal identifiable data - in real time, that's why these regulations and background checks are in place.